# Null pointer exception in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 using Checkstyle 6.5.0.201504121610

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I have the checkstyle plugin version 6.5.0.201504121610 installed with Eclipse Luna 4.4.2. When I right click on a Java source file and select Checkstyle and then Check Code Code with Checkstyle, I get an error:

```
'Checking files...' has encountered a problem. An internal error occured during: "Checking files...".
```

When I click on `<<Details` it shows:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Checking files...".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.io.Flushables.flush(Flushables.java:56)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PropertyCacheFile.flushAndCloseOutStream(PropertyCacheFile.java:135)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PropertyCacheFile.destroy(PropertyCacheFile.java:123)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.destroy(TreeWalker.java:499)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.process(Checker.java:299)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.Auditor.runAudit(Auditor.java:159)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckstyleBuilder.handleBuildSelection(CheckstyleBuilder.java:300)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.jobs.RunCheckstyleOnFilesJob.runInWorkspace(RunCheckstyleOnFilesJob.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I have also seen this on Eclipse Kepler. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

I am using an external checkstyle configuration file which is common to all projects.

Comment: Ok, appears to be fixed in 6.6: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/921